# There is a memory leak when sharing file URL using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have write code like this, And when I used instruments, I found a memory leak.

```
            NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
            UIActivityViewController *vc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[filePath] applicationActivities:nil];
            [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

leaks show in instruments

[image]

then, I try to share a NSString or NSURL(not file url). There is no memory leak.
So how can I share a file URL with no memory leak?

```
            NSURL *path = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://stackoverflow.com/"];
            UIActivityViewController *vc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[path] applicationActivities:nil];
            [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

From my investigation in Xcode allocation stack, every time I present `UIActivityViewController` for a file url, it leaks around 20-50 `CFString` objects which contains file's uniform identifier. For example when I pass a mp3 file it contains `"public.mp3"`.

I think these are created to checking which installed applications can open file and which don't.

You should file a bug report in order to let Apple to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
UIActivityViewController *vc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[filePath] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^
{ 
    vc=nil;
}];
[vc release];
```

Comment: I had try this. But the other phone received not a normal file, received a file with ".data" suffix like "3F533F3F3F.data"

Comment: What is your file type ? Is it static or dynamic ?

Comment: static.  such as .txt, .pdf , etc.   I just want to share the file from my App to others iPhone/iMac.

Comment: The updated answer is the same as the one I'm currently using. It's useful, but there is a memory leak.        Another question the `@"Name"`in
  `initWithActivityItems:@[@"Name", url]` is write wrong？

Comment: This is my last suggestion mate, if its not resolves your issue i am done with this :/

Comment: It's not working for me , But thank you very much.  : )